# Is there a way to compile with crtsqlrpgle without using QTEMP/QSQLPRE?

Tags: compilation, ibm-midrange, rpg

The process to create an object from a SQLRPGLE source member is a multi-step process:

1. The syntax of the SQL within the source member is checked to ensure it is valid.
2. A copy of the source member being compiled is moved to a source file QSQLPRE in QTEMP.
3. The SQL statements in the source member are converted to calls and the new source member is placed in the source file QSQLTEMP1 in QTEMP, as a RPGLE source type.
4. It is this source member that is compiled.

If step 2 of the proccess fails, RNF0733 is thrown. Is there any way to avoid this?

- Using an interactive job is not an option.
- Using crtBndRpg is not an option cause I need rpgPpOpt(*lvl2)

Comment: Did you try to create QSQLPRE with a longer record prior to using CRTSQLRPGI like indicated in the second level text of RNF0733 ?

Comment: that doesn´t work if you build with make, cause every command has its own job.

Comment: Ok, there is something missing here. You are obviously not using system standard tools to build you programs. Please let us know how you are building? What is Make? where is it coming from? Also, are there any precompilers (other than the RPGLESQL precompiler) in the job stream? Some tools inject a precompiler using routing entries in the subsystem.

Comment: Also show us your build script if you are using one.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with this additional commands in my Makefile:

1. system "dltObj LIB/compile objType(*FILE)"
2. system "crtSrcPf LIB/compile rcdLen(250)"
3. system "cpyFrmStmF fromStmF('$<') toMbr('/QSYS.LIB/LIB.LIB/COMPILE.FILE/$@.MBR')"